# difference between eindringen and dringen

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, comparison

What is the difference between:

- **dringen** with the following meanings: ('get through , penetrate, or go public')
- **eindringen** share also some meanings with the verb Dringen 'get throw, penetrate, go public'

Examples:

1. das Gerücht drang in die Öffentlichkeit (ein) `went puplic`
2. die Sonne drang durch die Wolken (ein)  `get through, penetrate`
3. das Wasser drang durch die Wände in den Keller (ein) `get through`
4. diese Erkenntnis ist noch nicht ins politische Bewusstsein (ein)gedrungen

So please tell me in which case I should write *eindringen, dringen* and why?

Comment: Just have a look at this:  
https://www.dict.cc/?s=eindringen  
https://www.dict.cc/?s=dringen

Comment: Soll 'get throw' nicht 'get thrown' oder 'get through' heißen? Letzteres, oder? Und was sagt das Wörterbuch, was der Unterschied ist?

Answer (score 4):

The **ein** in **eindringen** is an **in/into**. That's true for a lot of verbs:

> dringen (to pass a gap) — eindringen (to enter by passing a gap)
>
> fahren (to drive) – einfahren (to enter by driving)
>
> spritzen (to squirt) – einspritzen (to inject)

Sometimes the *ein* is an intensifier:

> lesen (to read) — einlesen (to read until you understand a topic)
>
> reden (to talk) — einreden (**to convince someone about the untruth**, to talk against an order)
>
> stellen (to put) – einstellen (to adjust)

Sometimes the derived meanings are hard to guess:

> fallen (to fall) – einfallen (**to come to mind**, to invade)
>
> gehen (to go) — eingehen (to incur, to gamble, **to die** – plants, sometimes animals)
>
> laufen (to run) — einlaufen (to run into, **to shrink by washing** – clothing)

---

So, to answer your question: Whenever someone or something enters something by passing a gap or leak, use ***ein**dringen*, if not, *dringen*.

Note there's also the verb **durchdringen** (emphasis on first syllable, separateable) which means the same as *dringen*, but passing the gap against some resistance, and, to confuse you by purpose, **durchdringen** (emphasis on second syllable, non-separateable) which means to soak, to interfuse.

Answer (score 1):

Janka already explained it fine. In my own words, I'd say: «*ein*dringen» focuses a specific destination—though abstract locations like «the public», «daylight», or «surface» do not count as penetrated destinations (but «mind» does).

To illustrate that on your examples:

1. «Das Gerücht drang **an** die Öffentlichkeit»:
   (**an** is more idiomatic) There is no specific destination, so «ein» is wrong.
2. «Die Sonne drang durch die Wolken»:
   (again, no specific destination)
3. «Das Wasser drang durch die Wände», but
   «Das Wasser drang **in** den Keller ein»:

   In the combined sentence, you may choose either «dringen» to focus on the path (through the wall and beyond) or «eindringen» to emphasize the destination.
4. «Diese Erkenntnis ist noch nicht **ins** politische Bewusstsein eingedrungen»:
   With an explicit destination, «eindringen» is the better choice.

As a rule of thumb, «eindringen» is the better choice, when the destination is mentioned explicit (with **in**) or implicit. In the latter case, «ein-» is a mandatory placeholder for the omitted destination:

- «Das Haus stand leer. Die Täter drangen bei Nacht [in das Haus] ein und entwendeten Geld und Wertgegenstände.»
- «Die Buchsen sind mit Kappen verschlossen, damit kein Schmutz [in das Gehäuse] eindringen kann.»

«Dringen» is only suitable when there is no specific destination (neither explicit nor implicit):

- «Wasser dringt durch die kleinste Ritze.»
- «Die Wahrheit dringt langsam ans Tageslicht.»

Answer (score 1):

Finally a native speaker gut feeling. **Dringen** is used when something moves with some level of force (sometimes metaphorically). **Dringen** is not used a lot colloquially a lot outside set phrase. E.g. **Das Gerücht dringt nach aussen.** 
**Eindringen** is far more widely used. Both literally and metaphorically in the sense of 'penetrate'.